# How to make Protractor's ElementArrayFinder 'each' function wait for the current action to complete before advancing to next iteration?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I am using protractor to do e2e tests in an Angular 8 app and I am currently having trouble making an 'each' loop work as I need. 
In my page object I have created a method that returns an ElementArrayFinder.

```
public getCards(): ElementArrayFinder {
return element.all(
  by.css(
    `${this.baseSelector} .board-body cs-medication-card`,
  ),
);
```

}

For each of the elements returned I want to perform a set of actions that consists in clicking in a button that opens a menu list (while the menu is open there is an overlay element over all the view except the menu list) and pick one of the options. In my test I have this:

```
await page.board
  .getCards()
  .each(async (el: ElementFinder) => {
    await until.invisibilityOf(await page.getOverlay());
    await el
      .element(by.css('.card-header .actions'))
      .getWebElement()
      .click();

    await expect(page.isItemInMenu('X')).toBeTruthy();
    await page
      .getMenuItemByLabel('X')
      .getWebElement()
      .click();
  });
```

I was expecting that for each card it would click the actions button, check if the option is in the list and click in the option.

What is happening is that it seems that protractor is trying to do everything at same time, since it says it cannot click on the actions button because the overlay is over it. The only way to the overlay be over the button is if the action in the previous iteration is not complete. I have already threw in the ExpectedCondition to wait for the overlay to be invisible but no luck. If only one element is returned by the ElementArrayFinder it does what is supposed.

I am out of ideas, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor's `each` is asynchronous. 
It's fine when you need to perform some action over an array of element (e.g get text or count) but it's not the best choice when you need to perform some kind of scenario. 
I'm suggesting to use any other way like `for` loop.

Another workaround (which again might not work because of async nature of `.each`) is FIRST to wait for overlay to appear and the wait for it to disappear.

Comment: The for loop worked but the wait approach within the `.each` didn't. Even with the `ExpectedConditions.wait(invisibility/visibility)` it does seem to wait for anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` function is almost of no use. It even doesn't wait for the promise returned by `each` Function.

```js
await $$('...').each((ele, index) => {
   return ele.$('.fake_class').click().then(() => {
       console.log(`the item ${index} is clicked.`)
       return browser.wait(5000)
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some issues in the function of `each`.

1. getWebElement() is unnecessary
2. await expect(page.isItemInMenu('X')).toBeTruthy();  seems wrong
3. await until.invisibilityOf(await page.getOverlay()); I'm not sure it work well.

Please try following code:

```
await page.board
  .getCards()
  .each(async (el: ElementFinder) => {
    // await until.invisibilityOf(await page.getOverlay());

    browser.sleep(10*1000) 
    await el
      .element(by.css('.card-header .actions'))
      .click();

    // expect(await page.isItemInMenu('X')).toBeTruthy();

    await page
      .getMenuItemByLabel('X')
      .click();
  })
  .catch((err)->{  // use catch() to capture any runtime error in previous each
    console.log('err: ' + err)
  })
```

If above code worked, you can revert back the `expect` and run again, then remove `browser.sleep()` and revert back your `await until.invisibilityOf(....)` and run again.

Comment: The problem seems to be the running of the iterations in parallel. I would expect that the 'await' keywords would make it run synchronously...